# Display related Weeks in Second Drop down

Tags: javascript, angular

I just create two drop down , first is month drop down , I want to display second drop down of weeks.
I try this code but fail.

```js
weeklist: string[] = [];
getWeeksInMonth(month, year) {
  var lenweek = [],
    week = [],
    firstDate = new Date(year, month, 1),
    lastDate = new Date(year, month + 1, 0),
    numDays = lastDate.getDate();
  var start = 1;
  var end = 7 - firstDate.getDay();
  while (start <= numDays) {
    week.push({
      start,
      end
    });
    lenweek.push("Week" + week.length);
    start = end + 1;
    end = end + 7;
    if (end > numDays)
      end = numDays;
  }
  this.weeklist = lenweek;
}
```

```html
<select class="weeks" #months (change)="addmonth(months.value)">
  <option>Select Month</option>
  <option *ngFor="let month of monthlist" [value]="month.count">
    {{ month.name }}
  </option>
</select>

<span>Select Week</span> <br>
<select class="weeks" #weeks (change)="addweeks(weeks.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let week of weeklist" [value]="week">
    {{ week }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Result for january

[image]

This result is same for all month.

Result for april

[image]

I Want Result Different Like For january Week1 to week5
Feb Week6 to Week 10 ,Mar Week 11 to Week 15 , upto December..Week 52,

Is this possible??

Answer (score 0):

A more simple approach

```
 Date.prototype.getWeek = function () {
      var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
      var today = new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), this.getDate());
      var dayOfYear = ((today - onejan + 86400000) / 86400000);
      return Math.ceil(dayOfYear / 7)
    };

    var today = new Date();

    var firstDay = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 1);
    var lastDay = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0);

    var weekNumberFirst = firstDay.getWeek();

    var weekNumberLast = lastDay.getWeek();
```

You can use the function to get the 2 week numbers, subtract it and you will get the number of weeks(length) in a month and then loop through those numbers and append `"Week "` to it. Hope it helps .